# devtools.jsonview.enabled Doesn't seem to affect developers tools

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

In the developers console, network tab, when examining the parameters sent with a request, if the parameters happen to be in JSON format, Firefox displays a garbage view, which prevents access to the JSON being sent (kind of like XML view in Eclipse).

This is a relatively new "improvement". Is there any way to undo it, aside from reverting to some older version of Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it in Firefox detailed configuration.

Enter:
`about:config` in the address bar then search for `devtools.jsonview.enabled` and set it on `false`.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick to accept this: no.  This doesn't work. I still see a crippled Eclipse-style garbage instead of the text of JSON response.